# Karma doesn't find files specified in config file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm writing Jasmine tests to my Angularjs app. 
I generated karma.conf.js using karma init but when I run karma start i get warnings like this:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /bower_components/angular/angular.js
WARN [web-server]: 404: /js/app.js
```

karma.conf.js is in my app folder, which is the place for the bower_components folder as well.

I think maybe that could be because of my local test server where I'm using this approach: https://github.com/mhevery/angular-node-socketio

(I've been able to set up the tests like this in other project without a test server)

Can anybody please point me in the right direction here?

---

**Update:**

My karma.conf.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'tests/*.js',
      'js/*.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/d3/d3.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Here's my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Could you add your karma.conf.js code and also your project directory structure?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but if you look at the angular seed project from the tutorial http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial you get the environment installed, and it does work for testing.  Run the server with the batch file/script and it will monitor your directory for changes and run the tests right away.

Comment: I think the problem is in your karma.conf.js `basepath`: could you try with `''` (without dot)? You should also change `logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,` to `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,` to see more info in the terminal.

Comment: That helped a bit I think, however, now I get:

 " Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined"

in my app.js file. My app.js file looks like this: 
angular.module('App', [
 'ngResource',
 'App.controllers',
 'App.factories',
 'App.directives',
 'App.filters'
]);

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've fixed the basepath (from '.' to '', see question comments above), you should change the order of files loading in your karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      //load angular.js first
      //(unless if you use jQuery which must be first if I remember well)
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      //Then angular-modules
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      //Other libs
      'bower_components/d3/d3.js',
      //Your app scripts
      'js/*.js',
      //And your specs 
      'tests/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

You can find more info here: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/files.html

> ### Ordering
>
> 1. The order of patterns determines the order of files in which they are included in the browser.
> 2. Multiple files matching a single pattern are sorted alphabetically.
> 3. Each file is included exactly once. If multiple patterns match the same file, it's included as if it only matched the first pattern.

Comment: Did you stop and restart karma? Karma cannot see karma config changes in autowatch.

Comment: We are obviously missing something. I guess that your app works correctly (in browser). Which scripts do you load in your index.html head?

Comment: In index.html I'm loading a file called commonScripts.js which uses document.write to add the following scripts:
angular.js, angular-mocks.js, angular-resource.js, d3.js, app.js, controllers.js, filters.js, directives.js and factories.js.
And yes, it works fine in browser.

Comment: Maybe the error comes from RequireJs? You do use it, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46938/discussion-between-glepretre-and-gelly)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably the order you're loading your files in.

You may need to change the order to something like:

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/d3/d3.js',
  'js/*.js',
  'tests/*.js'
],
```